# Spring-Boot-Admin application not starting because of error creating bean with name adminHandlerMapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I am following this [blog](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-admin/) to try out a Spring-Boot-Admin application. And when I run the app it fails with the below error:

```
Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'adminHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [de/codecentric/boot/admin/server/config/AdminServerWebConfiguration$ServletRestApiConfirguation.class]:
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I look further below and find these below lines:

```
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.web.servlet.AdminControllerHandlerMapping.withPrefix(AdminControllerHandlerMapping.java:48) ~[spring-boot-admin-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.web.servlet.AdminControllerHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AdminControllerHandlerMapping.java:44) ~[spring-boot-admin-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
```

Not sure if there is some circular dependency in the jars. Any idea please?

Comment: Hi. You should provide more details about your pom. Can you post it? Maybe you overlooked some step in the guide?

Comment: thnx fixed as mentioned in the answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comment by @the hand of NOD made me relook into my pom.xml file and the pom.xml file provided in the [blog](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-admin/)

The problem lies in the version number of the `spring-boot-starter-parent`. The tutorial uses a version **2.1.0.RELEASE** whereas the latest one when you prepare a project from [Spring Intializr](https://start.spring.io/) is **2.2.1.RELEASE**

I downgraded to 2.1.0.RELEASE and it worked! With 2.2.1.RELEASE there is some dependency that is going cyclic with `spring-boot-admin-starter-server`

P.S. It seems that the codecentric team is already working upon it and would release the 2.2.0 compliant version by 22 Nov 2019 (https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/milestones)

Comment: Any compatible spring-boot-admin-starter-admin version for spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.9? @raikumardipak

Answer (score 1):

It works for me upgrade `spring-boot-admin-starter-admin` to 2.2.4 and using
`spring-boot-starter-parent` 2.2.8.RELEASE, `spring-boot-admin-starter-client` 2.1.6 on service's pom

Comment: Any compatible spring-boot-admin-starter-admin version for spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.9?